# Change the Background of <td> by checking the value of a Checkbox inside it

Tags: jquery

Below is my code,  But it is not working..

```
    $('TABLE TBODY TR TD').click(function()
                         {
                        var color=$(this).css('background-color');
                        var x=$(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked');
                        if(x)
                        {
                         $(this).index();
                         $(this).css("background-color", "red");                          
                        }
                        });
```

Here is my HTML

```
    <table>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="radio"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="radio"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="radio"></td></tr>
    </table>
```

Please someone help me.

Comment: "It works" (the background gets red), you just don't see it because your cells have no other content: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/KkZdE/

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "not working"? What happens when you try the code, and how does that differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe an approach like this would work a little better.

```
$("td input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        $(this).parent("td").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Comment: @genesis, All you are doing is modifying a CSS property, very elementary jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) for animations. For normal CSS, you have to specify bind to click to INPUT button, not table cell

you'll have to modify as this

```
  $('TABLE TBODY TR TD input').click(function()
                     {


                     $(this).parent("td").css("background-color", "red");                          
                    }
                    });
```

Comment: sorry. Edited my anwer to something useful

Answer (score 0):

Your question says you want the background changed when the checkbox clicked, so do it like this:

```
$('td input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // change background color to $(this).parent();
    } else {
        // Turn off background color
    }
});
```

Disclaimer: not tested.

Comment: @genesis: Since when? Of course you can change the background color.

Answer (score 0):

Defining the event on `$('TABLE TBODY TR TD').click(function()` isn't going to work, because you want the event to change when the checkbox is clicked, not the cell.

You can either:

1. Define a class on the checkbox inputs, and in the `click` function, figure out which one was clicked and change the appropriate background color
2. Define a unique id on each of the checkboxes, but that would require adding a `click` function to each of the ids (which just means you're writing duplicate code, and isn't very clean)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :) .... is the color a fixed value are will be dynamic ... each checkbox a different color?

```
<table>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="colorswitcher"></td><td><input type="radio"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="colorswitcher"></td><td><input type="radio"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="colorswitcher"></td><td><input type="radio"></td></tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".colorswitcher").click(function() {
            if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(this).closest("td").css("background","#000");  
            }else {
               $(this).closest("td").css("background","#fff");
            } 
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('table td input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('td').css('background-color', $(this).prop('checked') ? 'red' : 'white');
    })
})
```

This is the easiest way to do it, it's tested.

Answer (score 0):

here is my examples:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>BBB</td>            
   </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>CCC</td>
        <td>CCC</td>
   </tr>
</table>

$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).parent().siblings('td').addClass("activ");
        $(this).parent("td").addClass("activ");
    }else{
        $(this).parent().siblings('td').removeClass("activ");
        $(this).parent("td").removeClass("activ");
    }
});


td.activ{
    background:yellow
}
```

[click :D](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivoss/ka2g2tb6/)